# Is it possible to run a portion of the script via command line?

Tags: jmeter

Is it possible to run a portion of the script via command line in JMeter?

Here is what I am trying to do. I have multi-thread groups in a script. Let's say one is Stepping Thread Group and another one is tear down thread group for the same samplers, CSV files etc. Everything is the same. Now I want to run sometimes only thread group and sometimes only Stepping Thread Group.

I know we can do it from the GUI by disabling the thread group, but I want to do it from the command line to avoid manual steps. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define number of threads for both Thread Groups using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P), like:

- For Stepping Thread Group:

  ```
  ${__P(stepping.threads,1)}
  ```

  [image]
- For tearDown Thread Group

  ```
  ${__P(teardown.threads,1)}
  ```

  [image]

Whenever you want to disable certain Thread Group from [command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) - just set the number of threads for the specific thread group to `0` via [`-J` command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)

i.e.

- `jmeter -Jstepping.threads=50 -Jteardown.threads=0 -n -t ...` - will run the Stepping Thread Group with 50 virtual users and will not run the tearDown Thread Group

and

- `jmeter -Jstepping.threads=0 -Jteardown.threads=1` - will not run the Stepping Thread Group and will run the tearDown Thread Group with 1 virtual user

---

Alternative solution would be running your JMeter test using [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) tool as the wrapper. Taurus provides [Modifications for Existing Scripts](http://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Modifications-for-Existing-Scripts) functionality so you will be able to enable/disable arbitrary Test Elements using simple declarative YAML syntax like:

```
---
execution:
  scenario:
    script: test.jmx
    modifications:
      disable:  # Names of the tree elements to disable
      - jp@gc - Stepping Thread Group (deprecated)
      enable:  # Names of the tree elements to enable
      - tearDown Thread Group
```

See [Navigating your First Steps Using Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/navigating-your-first-steps-using-taurus) article for more information.